# How to get to tomcat root after Jenkins install

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I was able to successfully install TomCat on my MacMini. http://[localhost]:8080/ took me to the Tomcat home page.

However after I installed Jenkins via the installer (outside of TomCat), it appears to have declared itself the root app. Browsing to http://[localhost]:8080/ now takes me to Jenkins home page and not TomCat root. Tried removing the apache-folder and re installing but no luck.

How do I get back to the TomCat default Root app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your Jenkins config file, and edit it, making sure you update the port in the file.  For example, on Ubuntu, if you used apt-get to install, the file is `/etc/default/jenkins` and you need to have (or add) the following line:

```
 HTTP_PORT=8090
```

This sets the port to `8090`, you can use whichever port you prefer.  Once you have that done, you can look [at this page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu) to setup your Apache config (if you want to not use the `:8090`  on the URL)

Hope that helps, let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: This is the post that is more relevant to my situation on the Mac http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474835/configure-jenkins-mac-os-x-native-package-to-run-in-a-different-port